# Jaspersoft studio adjust position of fields relative to height of other fields

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report in Jaspersoft Studio 6.15. and I hit a wall that I can't seem to break.

The thing is I need to align my Static and Text fields depending on Stretch/NoStretch of the previous one.

In my report I want to add few text fields along with their (static text)labels aligned horizontally like

ID :  $F{ID}

Name:  $F{Name}

Address:  $F{Address}

But I'm unable to align them. This is what I tried

```
Position Type: float (for all static text and fields)
Stretch Type: no stretch (for all static text and fields)
Stretch With Overflow: True (for all dynamic text fields)
```

The image shows what I get and what I want. Moreover, my text field's content is dynamic i.e. content size could vary.

This is what I get:
[image: This is what I get]

This is what it should be:
[image: This is what it should be]

I've read many forums but could not find a solution, please suggest.

Thanks

EDIT:

Now I am getting this:

[image: Now I am getting this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest each static and text field pair into a frame element:

```
        <frame>
            <reportElement ... positionType="Float"/>
            <staticText>
                ...
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                ...
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            ...
        </frame>
        ...
```

If the elements are to be included in the detail section, you can also create a separate band for each pair:

```
<detail>
    <band>
        <staticText>
            ...
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            ...
        </textField>
    </band>
    <band>
        ...
    </band>
    ...
</detail>
```

Comment: Hello, @dada67 can you explain to me how do you add this property in Jaspersoft studio 6.15? I do not see that property nor option.

Comment: You can add a frame element by dragging it from the Basic Element Palette.  Then you can nest existing elements into the frame by dragging them onto the frame element.
Multiple detail band can be added by right clicking on Detail in the Outline view and then choosing Add Detail Band.

Comment: Thanks, I found option to enclose elements into Frame. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Right, that's an easier way to do it.